# How do I make a batch variable = to a command answer?

Tags: batch-file, set

I have looked in quite a few places. Maybe I have not asked the right question, but I am now here. I am making a batch file to sense what the Operating system is.

My current attempt:

```
set os=systeminfo |find "OS Name"
```

EDIT: a WINDOWS batch file

EDIT: If a command returns a line in the console. How do I make a variable = the returned string. (This is my main question. Sorry if I was not very clear.)

Example:

varName = Command |find "String"

Comment: Currently only TESTING on a windows 8 platform. Program will primarily be used on other computers using XP and 7.

Comment: If the requirement is to test the current OS version, you might be able to use a little program I wrote called [OSTest.exe](http://www.westmesatech.com/wast.html). It allows you to test the current OS against a number of criteria.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS get caption ^|find /i "windows"') do (set #OS=%%a)

set #
```

Answer (score 2):

See how this works for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:: Routine by Aacini
::Identify OS
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('ver') do set ver=%%a
set Version=
for %%a in (95=95 98=98 ME=ME NT=NT 2000=2000 5.1.=XP 5.2.=2003 6.0.=Vista 6.1.=7 6.2.=8 6.3=8.1) do (
   if "!Version!" equ "this" (
      set Version=Windows %%a
   ) else if "!ver: %%a=!" neq "%ver%" (
      set Version=this
   )
)

::Identify bit
if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)" (
   set Type=64 bit
) else (
   set Type=32 bit
)

::Display result
echo %Version% %Type%
echo/
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

this

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=winver2_nt

and this

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=winver_bat

should do the work.Not sure if are updated to support Windows 8.
[Here are all build numbers.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**EDIT** (only checks if it is Windows XP or 7 - see comments bellow.Will work also on Windows home editions which have no `WMIC` command)

```
@echo off
for /f " tokens=4,5 delims=. " %%a in ('ver') do set /a wver=%%a%%b
if "%wver%" == "61" echo Windows7
if "%wver%" == "51" echo WindowsXP
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I am only checking to see if it is Windows XP or 7 because it is not going to be on any other systems.

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
UN=`uname`

echo $UN
```

In windows you can just examine the `OS` environment variable:

```
echo %OS%
```

Comment: I tried typing in `echo %OS%` and it printed out Windows_NT I'm looking for it to say something along the lines of "Microsoft Windows 8.1"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
wmic os get caption /value
```

There isa lot more of information. Try

```
wmic os get /value
```

Comment: works on test platform but it seems that there is an odd read error on the xp platform.

Comment: just tested on my old XP-machine: works fine. What does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a routine I wrote to do this. WMIC returns goofy names for some OS's and version number isn't robust enough since some versions are the same for server and workstation. This works for everything.

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :GetOS cap bit sp
echo %cap%%bit% (%sp%)
exit /b


:GetOS caption servicepack 
setlocal
set arc=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
set key="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
for /f "tokens=3*" %%a in (
  'reg query %key%^|findstr /i ProductName') do set cap=%%a %%b
for /f "tokens=3*" %%a in (
  'reg query %key%^|findstr /i CSDVersion') do set sp=%%a %%b
endlocal & set %1=%cap% & set %2=%arc% & set %3=%sp%
exit /b
```